# Estimate the singular values of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let we have matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 0 & \cdots \\
        0 & 1 & 2 & \cdots \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        \cdots & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Prove that $1 \le \sigma_{n-1} \le ... \le \sigma_1 \le 3$.

The singular values of $A$ equal to the square root of eigenvalues of $AA^* = \begin{bmatrix}
        5 & 2 & 0 & \cdots \\
        2 & 5 & 2 & \cdots \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        \cdots & 2 & 5 & 2 \\
        \cdots & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Now we can apply Gershgorin circle theorem and say that we have one circle with center in $5$ and radius $2$, $n-2$ circles with center in $5$ and radius $4$ and one circle with center in $1$ and radius $2$. So it gives us that all eigenvalues of $AA^*$ are in the segment $[0;9]$ and it means that $\sigma_{n-1} \le ... \le \sigma_1 \le 3$. But I do not know how to prove another inequality.

Thanks for any help or ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be the leading principal $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix of $A^\ast A$. You may apply the interlacing inequality $\lambda_n^\downarrow(A^\ast A)\le\lambda_{n-1}^\downarrow(B)\le\lambda_{n-1}^\downarrow(A^\ast A)\le\cdots$ (which follows from [Courant-Fischer minimax principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)) and Gerschgorin disc theorem to conclude.